# Reverse order of view sort

Tags: views

Ok so I've got this view, and it has a few dozen items. I want the last 3.

Sort ascending seems to work, however the events are in the opposite order than I want.

Sort descending pulls events back from June.

Is there any way to pull the events, but order them differently with views?

Comment: So basically you want pagination order the way it is, but reverse it inside one page?

Answer (score 3):

It seems you need to have pages ordered ascending, but inside a page descending. To do that, you need to query database in ascending order. Then reverse order of one page in template that renders it.

```
<?php

/**
 * @file  views-view-unformatted--yourviewname.tpl.php
 * Default simple view template to display a list of rows.
 *
 * @ingroup views_templates
 */
?>
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php /* foreach ($rows as $id => $row): // That's how it looks by default */ ?>
<?php foreach (array_reverse($rows, TRUE) as $id => $row): /* That's what you need */ ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: This broke my view, which has custom styling.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Well, here we show the way to do things. We are **not** going to make your work for you. If your styling wasn't quite ready for reversed order you asked for or if you just overrided previously overriden `.tpl` you haven't mentioned to us, it's either your concern or a matter for another question. Unless something went wrong in the exact area covered by a question - then I'll be willing to work some more on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To only show 3 items, change the settings in the "pager" section to "Display a specified number of items", and set the number of items to 3 in the settings (assuming you're using Drupal 7). Then you can use a filter of some sort to filter to the exact 3 you want using the post date or any other variable.